# Apple Watch set background image

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

How can I programmatically set my WatchKit App background image? I need to set this in code as it changes depending on variable size and we need to place a label over the image.

Answer (score 22):

It is not possible to *programatically* set the background image on an *entire Watch App page* in WatchKit... a background image for the whole page can at the current time only be set in Interface Builder it appears.

However, you *can* set a picture as a background behind a label, and make that image fill the screen:
[image: Set a background image on a Group in WatchKit]

1. Create a group in your WatchKit scene. You are likely to want to set custom size attributes for the view (e.g., under Size setting Width and Height as 'Relative to Container' with a value '1' to fill the scene.
2. Set your desired background image as the Background attribute for the group.
3. Place your label inside the group, and format it as desired.

This group image can also be set programmatically:

1. Set an IBOutlet for the group to your WatchKit Extension in the usual fashion, by Ctrl-dragging from the group to your Interface Controller class in the Extension.
2. Ensure your image is included as a 'Copy Bundle Resource' in your WatchKit App (not the Extension).
3. Set the background image in the `awakeWithContext` method of the Extension (assuming you called your IBOutlet 'group'):

   ```
   [self.group setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName.png"]];
   ```

   The two techniques are of course not mutually independent. You can set an initial image in Interface Builder, and then replace it programatically later if that is called for.

Comment: This saved me: "Ensure your image is included as a 'Copy Bundle Resource' in your WatchKit App (not the Extension)."

Comment: You can also do this (setBackgroundImage on a group) with image data that's pulled from a web service or another outside location (any NSData object can be used). So you don't necessarily need to have the image as part of the bundle. The extension will handle transmitting the image to the Apple Watch for you.

Comment: @SilviuSt, I can't find `Copy Bundle Resource` in my `WatchKit App` target settings

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Ca sa iti vada imaginea, dai click pe ea din XCode si in meniul din dreapta dai click pe prima chestie si ai acolo "Target membership" si bifezi sa fie si pentru watck kit app

Comment: @SilviuSt, Am reusit cu `setBackgroundImage` pe un `group` fara sa fie nevoie de ce ai zis tu :-?

Comment: Ce ziceam eu era pentru cazul in care setezi o imagine si nu ti-o vede si nu iti dai seama dc. Eu asta am patit si la asta este problema ta. Daca imaginea nu are target si pentru "your watch kit application" nu ti-o seteaza

Comment: @SilviuSt how do you add the image in the copy bundle resource in watchkit app (not extension)?

Comment: Try with a new image, drag it into project and you'll se there add to targets and check your watch kit app

Comment: @Duncan, I tested your solution, and here is the result:

Comment: can we resize background image programatically in watch app?

Answer (score 3):

I used `setBackgroundImageNamed:` and it worked. Just pass the name of the image along with the extension. Make sure that the image is in your WatchKit app bundle or your device-side cache

```
[self.groupA setBackgroundImageNamed:@"image.png"];
```