# watchkit image on top of image

Tags: ios, watchkit

How to put an images on top of another image based on model?

Ideally I'd like to have an image, what has positioned images and labels on it. If I use a group I could only post them one after another.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a group, set the background image of the group, as described here [Apple Watch set background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583708/apple-watch-set-background-image), and then add your foreground image and labels to that group

Comment: oh, yeah, I needed to add a group to the group, and set backgroundimages on both :) cheers